# Difference in difference marginal probability from logistic model

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, lsmeans

I am trying to estimate the interaction term from a glmer model as a marginal probability contrast using emmeans. I can calculate the difference in differences marginal probability, but I was assuming that given the interaction term in the regression model was significant, the corresponding emmeans estimate would also be significant. It's not. If I have in fact calculated it correctly, what is the intuition in a statistically significant interaction term in a non-linear model not translating to a statistically significant probability difference? I understand that whereas odds ratios remain constant over the range of a covariate, differences in probabilities change depending on the value, so is it just that? And if that's the case, how does one report these findings? e.g. "The interaction effect between x and z was found to be statistically significant on the odds ratio scale but not when calculated as a difference in probabilities..."

```
> summary(test_mod <- glmer(initiation_bin ~ period * DMT_eff + GENDER + age + (1|PATIENT_ID), nAGQ = 0, data = treat_study_period, family = "binomial"))
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 0) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: initiation_bin ~ period * DMT_eff + GENDER + age + (1 | PATIENT_ID)
   Data: treat_study_period

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2570.4   2611.2  -1278.2   2556.4     2502 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3802 -0.4885 -0.3499  0.7855  3.4993 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 PATIENT_ID (Intercept) 0.2789   0.5281  
Number of obs: 2509, groups:  PATIENT_ID, 1614

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             0.782608   0.191114   4.095 4.22e-05 ***
periodpost             -0.145077   0.135121  -1.074 0.282967    
DMT_effhigh            -1.701113   0.133809 -12.713  < 2e-16 ***
GENDERM                 0.230089   0.113108   2.034 0.041927 *  
age                    -0.015935   0.004671  -3.411 0.000647 ***
periodpost:DMT_effhigh -0.572917   0.205676  -2.786 0.005344 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) prdpst DMT_ff GENDER age   
periodpost  -0.302                            
DMT_effhigh -0.251  0.452                     
GENDERM     -0.118 -0.023 -0.053              
age         -0.866 -0.013 -0.074 -0.037       
prdpst:DMT_  0.185 -0.657 -0.640  0.006  0.027


> test_mod |> 
+   emmeans(~ period + DMT_eff, type = "response")
 period DMT_eff  prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 pre    low     0.574 0.0234 Inf    0.5281     0.619
 post   low     0.539 0.0259 Inf    0.4877     0.589
 pre    high    0.198 0.0158 Inf    0.1684     0.231
 post   high    0.107 0.0118 Inf    0.0862     0.133

Results are averaged over the levels of: GENDER 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale 


> (test_emm <- test_mod |> 
+   emmeans(~ period + DMT_eff, type = "response") |> 
+   regrid() |> pairs(reverse = T))
 contrast             estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 post low - pre low    -0.0358 0.0333 Inf  -1.074  0.7056
 pre high - pre low    -0.3768 0.0274 Inf -13.757  <.0001
 pre high - post low   -0.3410 0.0297 Inf -11.483  <.0001
 post high - pre low   -0.4672 0.0256 Inf -18.253  <.0001
 post high - post low  -0.4314 0.0280 Inf -15.401  <.0001
 post high - pre high  -0.0904 0.0193 Inf  -4.681  <.0001

Results are averaged over the levels of: GENDER 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 


> custom <- list(`DiD` = c(-1,0,0,0,0,1))
> contrast(test_emm, custom)
 contrast estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 DiD       -0.0546 0.0385 Inf  -1.418  0.1561

Results are averaged over the levels of: GENDER
```

The interaction term from the regression model:

```
periodpost:DMT_effhigh -0.572917   0.205676  -2.786 0.005344 **
```

and the emmeans probability estimate:

```
contrast estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 DiD       -0.0546 0.0385 Inf  -1.418  0.1561
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not computing the interaction effect, you are computing pairwise comparisons of cell means. You need interaction contrasts, e.g.

```
contrast(test_emm, interaction = "consec")
```

which will estimate consecutive differences of consecutive differences.

Comment: you could also do this with `contrast(regrid(test_emm), interaction = "consec")`